# upload multiple files with one file element(without multiple option). and select one file at a time

Tags: javascript, jsp, file-upload, struts-1, multiple-file-upload

I am looking for a solution to upload multiple files with a single File Element, (without using multiple option for HTML 5), and want to select one file at a time. After select one file that file will be visible below to delete(with a delete button). and can select other files also with the same File element but one by one.after click on save all the files will be saved to database. if anybody have already implemented this kind of thing can please help.

PS: i am using JSP as front and struts 1.2

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good example, [blueimp-jQuery file upload](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload)

It supports multiple file upload with drag and drop facility plus good UI.